# Singleton with CardLayout won't show card when another class calls Singleton.instance.show()

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

```
public class MainWindow extends JPanel {

public static MainWindow instance = new MainWindow();

private CardLayout cards = new CardLayout();

public MainWindow() {
    setLayout(cards);
    add(new FirstPage(), Pages.FIRST.toString());
    add(new SecondPage(), Pages.SECOND.toString());
    add(new ThirdPage(), Pages.THIRD.toString());
}

public void showPage(Pages page) {
    cards.show(this, page.toString());
}

}
```

the `showPage(page);` method works fine if I call it in the constructor of `MainWindow`. But when I try to call `MainWindow.instance.showPage(Pages.SECOND);` from an ActionListener in `FirstPage` nothing happens. I've checked that the `showPage(page)` method works correctly. I've checked that the ActionEvent is fired and enters the correct if/else clause. What am I doing wrong, why isn't my second page showing?

```
public class FirstPage extends JPanel {

    private JButton showSecond = new JButton("Show Second");
    private JButton showThird = new JButton("Show Third");

    public FirstPage() {
        insertButton(showSecond);
        insertButton(showThird);
    }

    private void insertButton(JButton button) {
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == showSecond) {
                    MainWindow.instance.showPage(Pages.SECOND);
                } else {
                    MainWindow.instance.showPage(Pages.THIRD);
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You really shouldn't be using a singleton for this sort of code. It looks to be dangerous code, and a non-singleton class should work just fine. 2) I don't see the code above showing the reason for your program's misbehavior, suggesting to me that the problem lies elsewhere in code not shown. Consider creating and posting a [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I know that I shouldn't. But my solution to all my access-problems are singletons. I just don't see how `FirstPage` would otherwise have access to the public method of `MainWindow`? I can't exactly give `FirstPage` a local reference without instantiating a new object.

Comment: @user2651804 You can always pass a reference of the controller to it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would suggest a reference issue. `public static MainWindow instance = new MainWindow();` looks suspicious, as you would have had to create an instance of `MainWindow` first for it to be initialise which suggests you now have two instances of `MainWindow`, one on the screen and one that is not

Using `static` in this way is a bad idea, as it leads to issues like this. Instead you should pass a reference of the controller to the page. The controller would define the actions that each page could perform (and if done right, would be defined as an `interface`)

Alternatively, you could separate the navigation from the pages into a separate mechanism, this means the pages don't care and can simply displayed in any order you want or reused else where

**Example #1 - Controller based pages**

This examples defines a simple controller which the pages can call in order to effect the navigation of the pages

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class CardLayoutExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CardLayoutExample();
    }

    public CardLayoutExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new Wizard());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface NavigationController {

        public void nextPage();

        public void previousPage();

        public void lastPage();

        public void firstPage();

    }

    public interface Page {

        public NavigationController getNavigationController();

        public JComponent getView();
        public String getName();

    }

    public class Wizard extends JPanel implements NavigationController {

        private List<Page> pages;
        private Page currentPage;

        private CardLayout cardLayout;

        public Wizard() {
            cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            pages = new ArrayList<>(25);
            setLayout(cardLayout);
            pages.add(new FirstPage("Page01", this));
            pages.add(new SecondPage("Page02", this));
            pages.add(new ThirdPage("Page03", this));

            for (Page page : pages) {
                add(page.getView(), page.getName());
            }

            firstPage();
        }

        @Override
        public void nextPage() {
            int index = pages.indexOf(currentPage);
            index++;
            if (index < pages.size()) {
                cardLayout.next(this);
                currentPage = pages.get(index);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void previousPage() {
            int index = pages.indexOf(currentPage);
            index--;
            if (index >= 0) {
                cardLayout.previous(this);
                currentPage = pages.get(index);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void lastPage() {
            Page page = pages.get(pages.size() - 1);
            showPage(page);
        }

        @Override
        public void firstPage() {
            Page page = pages.get(0);
            showPage(page);
        }

        protected void showPage(Page page) {
            cardLayout.show(this, page.getName());
            currentPage = page;
        }

    }

    public abstract class AbstractPage extends JPanel implements Page, ActionListener {

        private NavigationController navigationController;
        private JPanel buttons;
        private String name;

        public AbstractPage(String name, NavigationController navigationController) {
            this.name = name;
            this.navigationController = navigationController;
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        protected void insertButton(JButton button) {
            button.addActionListener(this);
            buttons.add(button);
        }

        @Override
        public NavigationController getNavigationController() {
            return navigationController;
        }

        @Override
        public JComponent getView() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return super.getName(); 
        }

    }

    public class FirstPage extends AbstractPage implements Page {

        private JButton next = new JButton("Next >");

        public FirstPage(String name, NavigationController controller) {
            super(name, controller);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("First page");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(label);
            insertButton(next);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == next) {
                getNavigationController().nextPage();
            }
        }

    }

    public class SecondPage extends AbstractPage implements Page {

        private JButton next = new JButton("Next >");
        private JButton previous = new JButton("< Previous");

        public SecondPage(String name, NavigationController controller) {
            super(name, controller);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Second page");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(label);
            insertButton(previous);
            insertButton(next);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == next) {
                getNavigationController().nextPage();
            } else if (e.getSource() == previous) {
                getNavigationController().previousPage();
            }
        }

    }

    public class ThirdPage extends AbstractPage implements Page {

        private JButton previous = new JButton("< Previous");

        public ThirdPage(String name, NavigationController controller) {
            super(name, controller);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Third page");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(label);
            insertButton(previous);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == previous) {
                getNavigationController().previousPage();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Example #2 - central controller example**

This example separates the controller from the pages, so that the buttons are not part of the pages themselves.  This frees up the pages/views to be anything you need them to be

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class CardLayoutExample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CardLayoutExample2();
    }

    public CardLayoutExample2() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new WizardPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class WizardPane extends JPanel {

        private List<String> pages;
        private String currentPage;

        private JButton first;
        private JButton previous;
        private JButton next;
        private JButton last;

        private CardLayout cardLayout;
        private JPanel contentPane;

        public WizardPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            pages = new ArrayList<>(3);

            contentPane = new JPanel(cardLayout);
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

            pages.add("Page01");
            pages.add("Page02");
            pages.add("Page03");

            contentPane.add(new FirstPage(), "Page01");
            contentPane.add(new SecondPage(), "Page02");
            contentPane.add(new ThirdPage(), "Page03");

            JPanel actionsPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            actionsPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            actionsPane.add((first = new JButton("<< First")), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            actionsPane.add((previous = new JButton("< Previous")), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            actionsPane.add((next = new JButton("Next >")), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            actionsPane.add((last = new JButton("Last >>")), gbc);

            add(contentPane);
            add(actionsPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            NavigationHandler handler = new NavigationHandler();
            first.addActionListener(handler);
            previous.addActionListener(handler);
            next.addActionListener(handler);
            last.addActionListener(handler);

            gotoFirstPage();
        }

        protected void gotoFirstPage() {
            currentPage = pages.get(0);
            cardLayout.show(contentPane, currentPage);
        }

        protected void gotoPreviousPage() {
            int index = pages.indexOf(currentPage);
            index--;
            if (index >= 0) {
                currentPage = pages.get(index);
                cardLayout.show(contentPane, currentPage);
            }
        }

        protected void gotoNextPage() {
            int index = pages.indexOf(currentPage);
            index++;
            if (index < pages.size()) {
                currentPage = pages.get(index);
                cardLayout.show(contentPane, currentPage);
            }
        }

        protected void gotoLastPage() {
            currentPage = pages.get(pages.size() - 1);
            cardLayout.show(contentPane, currentPage);
        }

        protected class NavigationHandler implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == first) {
                    gotoFirstPage();
                } else if (e.getSource() == previous) {
                    gotoPreviousPage();
                } else if (e.getSource() == next) {
                    gotoNextPage();
                } else if (e.getSource() == last) {
                    gotoLastPage();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class FirstPage extends JPanel {

        public FirstPage() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Page One");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(label);
        }

    }

    public class SecondPage extends JPanel {

        public SecondPage() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Page Two");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(label);
        }

    }

    public class ThirdPage extends JPanel {

        public ThirdPage() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Page Three");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(label);
        }

    }
}
```

**Example #3 - Model based**

Or you could use a model based approach (which is probably more preferable), which defines the order in which components are displayed. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350197/cant-call-a-the-third-page-via-the-2nd-page/18350351#18350351)

Comment: Yeah.. I tried to create a new MainWindow when adding it to my JFrame. =)

Comment: Could you please show in code, or try to elaborate on one or both of these methods to improve my design? I'm really, really curious.

Comment: You can override actionPerformed in `FirstPage` without implementing ActionListener because `AbstractPage` implements it. Then why do you implement the `Page` interface in both `AbstractPage` and `FirstPage`?

Comment: @user2651804 `Page` defines what a individual page can do.  I want all class that extend `AbstractPage` to also be able to use the methods from `Page`.  This is the glue which binds the concept together.  `AbstractPage` is a fun class, because it pretty much defines all the functionality of `Page` so other classes which extend from it don't have to.  If you didn't do it this way, you would end up repeating the contract requirements for `Page` in `FirstPage`, `SecondPage` and `ThirdPage` and so on. When I see repeated code, I look to ways to reduce this duplication