# how to return to my main panel in java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout, jmenuitem

I want to back to the main panel in my java application with a jMenuItem, my panels and other stuff are set with a CardLayout. So I have 3 panels and from any of them I want to be able to return to the first panel using this menu item to start a new analysis. I have tried with the property setVisible with no results. Any suggestion? thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Use a controller which is passed to each panel which "knows" how to make the navigation work, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296505/how-to-effectively-use-cardlayout-in-java-in-order-to-switch-from-panel-using-bu/24296872#24296872) or [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352226/singleton-with-cardlayout-wont-show-card-when-another-class-calls-singleton-ins/23352348#23352348)

Comment: How about removing the panel from the parent container and use the revalidate() method ?

Comment: @JalalSordo: so you're going to recommend that he forgo use of CardLayout, the preferred way to swap views in Swing and instead jerry rig it by hand? No thank you please.

Comment: Yes as long as he has just started putting the ui, and he won't change a lot of code.

Comment: I had a similar project.  Its hard to describe the all conditions in few words. However, I made my main panel as singleton. If I call getInstance() it return a new main panel. now I call either home or list view or any other view from the object from getInstance().

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

The below example may help you.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class cardLayout {
    JFrame objFrm = new JFrame("CardLayout Demo");
    JPanel pnl1, pnl2, pnl3, pnlMain;
    JMenuBar mBar;
    JMenu mnu;
    JMenuItem mnuItem;
    public void show() {
        pnl1 = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        pnl1.add(new JLabel("Panle 1"));
        pnl2 = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        pnl2.add(new JLabel("Panle 2"));
        pnl3 = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        pnl3.add(new JLabel("Panle 3"));

        pnlMain = new JPanel();
        pnlMain.setLayout(new CardLayout());

        pnlMain.add(pnl1);
        pnlMain.add(pnl2);
        pnlMain.add(pnl3);

        objFrm.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        objFrm.add(pnlMain);

        objFrm.setSize(300, 300);
        mBar = new JMenuBar();
        mnu = new JMenu("Menu");
        mnuItem = new JMenuItem("Change Panel");
        mnuItem.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
            ((CardLayout) pnlMain.getLayout()).next(pnlMain);
        });
        mBar.add(mnu);
        mnu.add(mnuItem);
        objFrm.setJMenuBar(mBar);
        objFrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        objFrm.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new cardLayout().show();
    }
}
```

At first i added the three Jpanels(pnl1,pnl2,pnl3) to JFrame having card layout and it didn't worked and throw error. So instead i created one more panel (pnlMain) with cardlayout and added all the three panels. And now it worked fine on menu item click event.